# Invoke-Command fails to create the Process

Tags: windows, mongodb, powershell, invoke-command, alteryx

Why does EmongoDump of Alteryx fail in PowerShell when I run a script using `Invoke-Command`?

When I run it normally, I get this success message:

> Command line: "E:\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxService_MongoController.exe" MongoRoot="E:\Alteryx\bin\" DBName=AlteryxService DBRoot="E:\AlteryxServer\Service\Persistence\MongoDB" Port=27100 IPV6=False DumpPath="E:\Path" EMongoDump running..finished.

When I run it using `Invoke-Command`:

> Command line: "E:\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxService_MongoController.exe"
>   MongoRoot="E:\Alteryx\bin\" DBName=AlteryxService DBRoot="E:\AlteryxServer\Service\Persistence\MongoDB" Port=27100 IPV6=False DumpPath="E:\Path" EMongoDump failed: Failed to create process: Access is denied.

I am an administrator and have also started the RemoteRegistry service using:

```
Get-Service remoteregistry -ComputerName $computer | Start-Service
```

where `$computer` is the server to execute the script on.

`Invoke-Command` that I am using:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer "E:\Scripts\t1.ps1"
```

`t1.sp1` contains:

```
net stop AlteryxService
$alteryx = "E:\Alteryx\bin\AlteryxService.exe" 
& $alteryx emongodump=E:\Path
net start AlteryxService
```

I have tried to use a `-Scriptblock`. It shows the same error message then too.

I have also used `-Credential $username` where it prompts me to input a password and still the same issue occurs.

What is the issue and how is it resolved?

Comment: Are u using -credentials at the end to connect to your computer. Your command should like this 
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer "E:\Scripts\t1.ps1" -Credential username which will give up a pop up to enter the password

Comment: Also invoke command is used to run command on remote machine

Comment: Yes. I've tried -Credential. I've edited the question to add that detail also.

Comment: Did you enable the remoting on the machine . here is a link https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: I can run commands like stopping and starting services remotely. Only the database dump command is the issue.

Comment: could it be CREDSSP. It is something which is used to send the credentials from client to server. Below follow the below link and see if it makes any difference https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/847119/Resolve-Double-Hop-Issue-in-PowerShell-Remoting

Comment: Ever get this working? Does the user in question have write access to Mongo, and does it also have write access to the dump target?  Can you log onto the target computer using the credentials supplied, and run the command there locally?